# Derivative of a flow diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ be a manifold, $V$ a smooth vector field on it and $\phi_t:M \rightarrow M$ its flow is defined for all $t\in R$. Can $d\phi_t$ be expressed in terms of $V$?

Comment: Sort of. At least if $M=\Bbb R^n$, I think that $d(\phi_t)_p$ is the solution to the non-autonomous matrix-valued differential equation: $$\partial_t S_t = dV_{\phi_t(p)} S_t,\;\;\;\;\; S_0=I.$$

Comment: ...where $dV_p$ is the derivative of $V$, viewed as a map from $\Bbb R^n$ to itself.